# Is it correct to delete a tuple from my query result which has been populated from a sql statement?

Tags: mysql, sql

I am learning sql queries. If my query result comes back like the picture given [query result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/12kCJ.png), is that a valid query result? If not what should I do to get back the result as solid table where it shouldn't let me edit the result. I am using phpmyadmin.

The query was to list all the student that doesn't provide the NOK details.
my sql statement is given below:

```
select CONCAT(s.fname,' ', s.lname) as Names,s.bannerNo 
from Student s
where NOT EXISTS (select*from NOK n where n.studentID = s.bannerNo)
```

**Student table**:

```
Student (bannerNo,fName,lName, street,city,postcode,mobile,email,DOB,gender,category,nationality,special needs, comments,status,courseNo,staffNo)
Primary Key bannerNo
```

**NOK Table**:

```
NOK (StudentID,fName,lName,relationship,street,city,postcode,phoneNo)
Primary Key StudentID
Foreign key StudentID references Student(bannerNo)
```

Comment: If you are getting a result; it basically **implies** that it is a valid query. Result is correct or not, depends on your actual requirements. Why do you need the result as not-editable. PHPMyAdmin automatically determines if editable or not, based on whether a primary or unique key column is available in the result-set

Comment: I thought it might be a wrong thing if i can edit the tuples from my query result, I got the right answer but just worried if this kind of outcome considered to be wrong. For other queries, i didn't have anything like that. Thats why wanted to make sure this is an accepted query result.@MadhurBhaiya

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly you want to delete a tuple on the visual tool (phpmyadmin) that shows you the result of the query.

I don't know the tool, but it does show the "Delete" button, as your image proves.

Let me translate this into SQL terms: you are seeing a "resultset" and you want to know if it's valid to manipulate it, so it will affect the underlying data. Did I get it right?

If so, then this question is similar to the manipulation of data using views. A view is a projection of one or more tables. Then... **are views updatable**? The answer is: some of them are.

Which ones? That depends on the database engine. Oracle is quite good at those; other database don't really allow it but in a small number of cases.

So, what's the main idea, then? Well in most databases the main concept is about "traceability". Does each resulting row correspond to a single row in one underlying table? If this is the case, then most likely you'll be able to update/delete it. If not, you're out of luck.

Why? Because, the database engine needs to have some way back to the source of the data you are viewing. If your query includes the primary key of the table, that's good news. If not, then it will be more difficult. Maybe some other column has a unique constraint or something that can be of use.

Bottom line, it depends on:

- The database engine (MySQL in this case).
- The "traceability" of the specific query. Can it be traced back to the rows? Seems so in your query, since the PK `bannerNo` is right there.

Comment: Nicely explained, I've understood the concept.  Thank you